# Error in R with 'Output format 'html' is not supported in commonmark' when using tbl_summary(mtcars) in gtsummary

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, gtsummary

I'm facing an issue when trying to use the tbl_summary function from the gtsummary package in R. When I run the following code:

```
library(gtsummary)
tbl_summary(mtcars)
```

I receive the following error:

```
Error in value[[3L]](cond): Output format 'html' is not supported in commonmark.
Additionally: Warning message:
In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) : path[1]="\\my\path\to\normalizePath(path.expand(path), Ð>
```

I have looked into CommonMark, but I'm unable to understand why the HTML output format would not be supported. Could someone please help me understand what might be causing this issue, and how I can resolve it?

Additional Information:

```
R version: 4.3.1
gtsummary package version: 1.7.2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

i am using all nessecery packages:

```
sessionInfo()

R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default


attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] markdown_1.7           survivalAnalysis_0.3.0 finalfit_1.0.6        
 [4] ggsurvfit_0.3.0        gtsummary_1.7.2        survminer_0.4.9       
 [7] ggpubr_0.6.0           survival_3.5-5         janitor_2.2.0         
[10] lubridate_1.9.2        forcats_1.0.0          stringr_1.5.0         
[13] dplyr_1.1.2            purrr_1.0.1            readr_2.1.4           
[16] tidyr_1.3.0            tibble_3.2.1           ggplot2_3.4.2         
[19] tidyverse_2.0.0       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_1.2.0     fastmap_1.1.1        broom.helpers_1.13.0 digest_0.6.33       
 [5] rpart_4.1.19         timechange_0.2.0     lifecycle_1.0.3      magrittr_2.0.3      
 [9] compiler_4.3.1       sass_0.4.7           rlang_1.1.1          tools_4.3.1         
[13] utf8_1.2.3           gt_0.9.0             data.table_1.14.8    knitr_1.43          
[17] ggsignif_0.6.4       xml2_1.3.5           abind_1.4-5          withr_2.5.0         
[21] nnet_7.3-19          grid_4.3.1           fansi_1.0.4          jomo_2.7-6          
[25] xtable_1.8-4         colorspace_2.1-0     mice_3.16.0          scales_1.2.1        
[29] iterators_1.0.14     MASS_7.3-60          cli_3.6.1            generics_0.1.3      
[33] km.ci_0.5-6          tzdb_0.4.0           tidytidbits_0.3.2    minqa_1.2.5         
[37] splines_4.3.1        survMisc_0.5.6       vctrs_0.6.3          boot_1.3-28.1       
[41] glmnet_4.1-7         Matrix_1.5-4.1       carData_3.0-5        car_3.1-2           
[45] hms_1.1.3            mitml_0.4-5          rstatix_0.7.2        foreach_1.5.2       
[49] glue_1.6.2           nloptr_2.0.3         pan_1.8              codetools_0.2-19    
[53] cowplot_1.1.1        stringi_1.7.12       gtable_0.3.3         shape_1.4.6         
[57] lme4_1.1-34          munsell_0.5.0        pillar_1.9.0         htmltools_0.5.5     
[61] R6_2.5.1             KMsurv_0.1-5         lattice_0.21-8       backports_1.4.1     
[65] broom_1.0.5          snakecase_0.11.0     Rcpp_1.0.11          gridExtra_2.3       
[69] nlme_3.1-162         xfun_0.39            zoo_1.8-12           pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

Comment: Could you please share your complete code including the YAML of your Rmarkdown file?

Comment: Ty for the question.
rn i am only running the code on a blank r file
so the complete code that is executed is this :

`library(gtsummary)
tbl_summary(mtcars)`

Comment: Updating `commonmark` solved it for me. I had troubles using `ggtext::element_textbox()` though.